# Survival Analysis - integrating the survival probability

Tags: actuarial-science

recently I am doing 1 question

A life aged (40) is subject to an extra risk for the next year only. Suppose the normal
probability of death is 0.003, and that the extra risk may be expressed by adding the function
0.03(1-t) to the normal force of mortality for this year. What is the probability of survival to
age 41?

I can write the function as

[image]

and I can get

[image]

However, I am not very sure how can I integrate the μ and get the correct answer.
Could you please see if there are any thing wrong on my calculation? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that $\mu_{40+s}=0.003$. So the probability of survival to age 41 is approximately $98.22\%$. Or the probability to die in between the next year is approximately $1.78\%$

Comment: @callculus42 thanks for your comment. So to clarify, I can directly substitute the integral of μ40+s into 0.003? thanks again

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Probably you should look at you notes what the definition of $\mu_{t+s}$ is.